# how to extract value in second column of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<tbody id="rankwyz-blogs">
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>
         <div class="checker"><span><input name="pid" type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="3350239"></span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">blog</td>
      <td>
         <a href="http://anonym.to/?http://jaysonlrrv.blog.com" target="_blank">http://jaysonlrrv.blog.com</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td>
         <div class="checker"><span><input name="pid" type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="3350241"></span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">blog</td>
      <td>
         <a href="http://anonym.to/?http://dewaynecypn.blog.com" target="_blank">http://dewaynecypn.blog.com</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to write a javascript/jQuery that would extract the value of the third td. So in this case I wanted the output to be:

```
http://jaysonlrrv.blog.com
http://dewaynecypn.blog.com
```

what is the best and most efficient way to do this?

Comment: The checkboxes are just for decoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult. Loop through `tr` elements and get the 3rd column:

```
$(function () {
    var urls = [];
    $('#rankwyz-blogs tr').each(function () {
        urls.push($(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
    });

    alert(urls);
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o5kn5x2b/).

Answer (score 1):

You may do this with JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#rankwyz-blogs tr').each(function(i, tr){
    console.log($(tr).find('td').eq(2).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below would be the most efficient way:

```
$("#rankwyz-blogs tr").each(function(){
    alert($(this).children("td").last().children("a").text());
});
```

**UPDATE:**

You need to add `<table>` before your `<tbody>`, check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmac1ke7/)..